# Cannot get Rating value in rating bar Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I don't accomplish to get the rating bar (with a fixed rating value) in my ListView using SimpleAdapter.

Here the code to set the value of rating:

```
String[] from={"nome","descrizione","prezzoVisita","valutazione","prezzoInterventoScontat‌​o","foto"}; 

int[] to={R.id.nomeClinica,R.id.descrizioneClinica,R.id.prezzoVisita,R.id.ratingBar1,R‌​.id.prezzoInterventoScontato,R.id.fotoClinica}; 
SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter( getApplicationContext(), cliniche,R.layout.cliniche_view,from, to);

adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                    String textRepresentation) {
                if(view.getId() == R.id.ratingBar1){
                    String val = (String) data.toString();
                    float ratingValue = Float.parseFloat(val);
                    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) view;
                    ratingBar.setRating(ratingValue);
                    return true;
                }

                    return false;
                }
            } );
         ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.clinicheListView)).setAdapter(adapter);
         ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.clinicheListView);
```

I got the ListView, except for the rating stars. 
SUggestions??

Comment: can you post the adapter initialization code

Comment: `String[] from={"nome","descrizione","prezzoVisita","valutazione","prezzoInterventoScontato","foto"};
int[] to={R.id.nomeClinica,R.id.descrizioneClinica,R.id.prezzoVisita,R.id.ratingBar1,R.id.prezzoInterventoScontato,R.id.fotoClinica};
SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(),
                cliniche,//sorgente dati
                R.layout.cliniche_view, //layout contenente gli id di "to"
                from,
                to);`

Comment: You have to define you own adapter and that will set the value of rating bar.... you can easily google that "how to make custom adapter for spinner"....